ぎおんまつり　written with two different kanji for ぎ
In the beginners textbook I am using to learn Japanese I have found that ぎおんまつり　is written with different kanjis for the ぎ.
I cannot write them, so I attach both as images:
 and 
Is this an alternate writing of the same kanji, or are they different kanji? What is the preferred writing ?

Yes, they are the same character.
There are forms of kanji called shinjitai (new, simplified form) and kyuujitai (old form). As part of this simplification project, the radical 示 ("shimesuhen", meaning religion/ceremony) was simplified to its cursive form, 礻. So, for example, 社 used to look like this: 
Now, 祇 lies in a bit of a gray area, because it's not a jouyou (or touyou) kanji. Officially, it was never simplified. To quote wikipedia:

The simplification in shinjitai were only officially applied to characters in the Tōyō and Jōyō Kanji Lists, with the kyūjitai forms remaining the official forms of Hyōgaiji (表外字, characters not included in the Tōyō and Jōyō Kanji Lists) ... Despite this, simplified forms of hyōgaiji do exist in Japanese character sets, and are referred to as extended shinjitai (拡張新字体). However, they are to be seen as unofficial ...

